# Communication between two arduino using digital pins

Tags: arduino

I want to virtually simulate a flow sensor with a second Arduino that is getting controls from a PC through Serial COM port.
The flow sensor is a hall effect sensor so it either transmits LOW or HIGH level.

Is it safe to directly connect a digital output pin from #1 Arduino to digital input pin in #2 Arduino? Should a resistor or a diode put between the two pins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you also connect the two grounds.  That's the point of digital inputs and outputs.

There should be no need for a series resistor unless you are doing something unusual.

Comment: If I connect the two grounds should they be on the same voltage source?

Comment: @Papai: Huh?  Connecting the two ground means running a wire from the ground of one unit to the ground of the other unit.

Comment: Since Arduino is usually a development environment (and things may go wrong), and there is no harm in a series resistor between output and input, I'd advise to use one. I usually use 220 or 330 ohm between microcontrollers/Arduino's signal pins. The maximum current will be limited to about 20mA when things accidentally go wrong.

Comment: @papaiatis they can be on different voltage sources and share the ground only (+ signal of course).